# Delphi Type library editor Refresh creates duplicates of all inherited Interface members in derived class implementation files

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Using the delphi Type Library editor,

If I create an interface with several properties and then a second interface which inherits from the first interface....when I press the refresh button which updates all the implementation files, duplicates of all the property getters and setters from the inherited class are created in the derived class implementation file.

Kind of defeats the object of inheritance really and its a bit annoying as I have go to around deleting all the spurious code and it happens to all the objects even when a small non-related change is made.

Is there any way to stop the Type Library IDE from generating all this unnecessary code?

Comment: Maybe by design?  I'll be interested to see an informed answer to your q because I've always found MS's take on COM somewhat impenetrable: I'm not sure COM f..i. supports interitance in the sense that Delphi's class system does.

Comment: @MartynA COM itself has no notion of class inheritance.

Comment: @Olivier:  Thanks, I was having a hard time imagining how an interface could hand-off supporting an interface to an ancestor interface.